# PostgreSQL won't add columns to existing tables in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, database-migration, rails-postgresql

I'm using `paranoid` gem to be able to mark records as deleted without actually deleting them.
To mark records as deleted it uses an additional column `deleted_at`

I have a migration which adds such column to all activerecord subclasses:

```
class AddDeletedAtToModels < ActiveRecord::Migration


def up
  Dir[Rails.root.join('app/models/**.rb')].each{ |f| require f }
  ActiveRecord::Base.subclasses.each do |klass|
    add_column klass.table_name.to_sym, :deleted_at, :datetime rescue Rails.logger.error("Can't add column to #{klass}")
  end
end

def down
  Dir[Rails.root.join('app/models/**.rb')].each{ |f| require f }
  ActiveRecord::Base.subclasses.each do |klass|
    remove_column klass.table_name.to_sym, :deleted_at
  end
end
```

end

But that migration fails with an error:

```
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::Error: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block:           
      SELECT attr.attname
      FROM pg_attribute attr
      INNER JOIN pg_constraint cons ON attr.attrelid = cons.conrelid AND attr.attnum = cons.conkey[1]
      WHERE cons.contype = 'p'
        AND cons.conrelid = '"schema_migrations"'::regclass
```

I'm not very familiar with postgresql, so the question is what that kind of error means and what am i doing wrong. That worked fine for MySQL but not for PostgreSQL.

Comment: so you want to add deleted_at field to all of you models, right?

Comment: @Muntasim
Yes, that is right

Comment: can you run the other migrations without this? it seems you have others broken migrations. the above code seems fine

Comment: @Muntasim 
You are right, i had a model but a migration that creates the table for the model was run after adding deleted_at columns. So it tried to add that column to a non-existing table. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just FYI, you shouldn't try to add this migration to every model file like you have. Migrations are supposed to be sequential. Consider what would happen if you needed to run all migrations in the future after adding more models (this migration would run before any newer model's creation migrations).